# Changing the shipping calculation in magento

Tags: magento

I have a magento shop which uses shipping zones method for calculating shipment price.

It works but there is one small issue , I am unable to offer quantity discounts for the same product if the user adds to his cart multiple times with different color. Each time the product is added it is taken as a separate products.

For example:

- shipping 1 unit of product x (irrespective of color) costs 20 USD
- shipping 4 units of product x (irrespective of color) costs 50 USD (i.e 30 USD quantity discount... the more the quantity, the less per unit cost)

Now if the customer choose 4 black tables the shipment cost is correctly calculated as 50 usd, but if the customer chooses 1 black, 1 white, 1 green and 1 red the calculation is incorrectly calculated as 80 USD.

How can I fix this issue? Magento should be taking into account 4 quantity of the same product and NOT 4 different products.

Comment: Have you tried "shopping cart rules"?

Comment: As Dick mentioned, you can use the 'shopping cart rules' to accomplish this.

One way would be to base your attribute sets on your shipping rates, and create a new rule in the backend to add a price, instead of discount.

Example:

Attribute Set: fifty-dollar-shipping
Tables : 50 usd 

Attribute Set: forty-five-dollar-shipping
Chairs : 45 usd

Just an example, there are other ways to do this in shopping cart rules. An easier approach would be to apply this rule to a table category IF all shipping rates are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is achievable with Shopping Cart Rules, particularly if you want your delivery costs to be separate to the product prices (from an accounting point of view you may want to keep track on delivery).

Hence...

...you need to write your own shipping module.

Here is the tutorial I have found to be of the most use:

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-shipping-method

Included in the tutorial are lots of examples of how to iterate over the cart and apply custom rules.

A module may seem a lot of work, however, once you have something you will be able to do a better job of shipping, for the customer, the company book keeper and the bottom line.